# PropTypes.node still throws invalid prop type error

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a `<Contact heading={<Fragment>Get in touch<span id="dot">.</span></Fragment>} />` component.

Inside `Contact.js`, I was using `<Heading {...props} />` component with:

```
Heading.propTypes = {
  heading: PropTypes.string,
}
```

But got this error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `heading` of type `object` supplied to `Contact`, expected `string`.
```

So I changed my PropTypes to:

```
Heading.propTypes = {
  heading: PropTypes.node,
}
```

(...after trying a bunch of combinations of PropTypes) so it would stop complaining, but it keeps throwing a similar error depending on which PropType I set.

I thought `.node` was just "Accept anything"...

How can I fix this annoying error, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was because I forgot to set PropTypes in `Contact.js`.

Adding

```
heading: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.string,
  PropTypes.object,
]),
```

to both `Contact.js` and `Heading.js` fixed it.